# Resize table AND text inside with window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get a table and its text to be re-sized with the window size with preferably just html and css but can try js if needed. I have seen a couple similar examples but none quite with my situation. If I need to rewrite the table to make this work, I have no problem with that.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sd3gtght/)

```
<section id="scheduleInfo">
<h1 style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><a href="members_home.html" style="text-decoration: none;"><-Back</a></h1>
<h1 style="text-align:center;">Your Personalized Maintenance Schedule</h1>  
<table class="schedule" border="1" summary="scheduleSummary" align="center">
        <caption></caption>
        <colgroup>
            <col class="maintItem" />
            <col class="maint1" />
            <col class="maint2" />
            <col class="maint3" />
            <col class="maint4" />
            <col class="maint5" />
            <col class="maint6" />
            <col class="maint7" />
            <col class="maint8" />
            <col class="maint9" />
            <col class="maint10" />
        </colgroup>
            <thead id="maint">
                <tr>
                    <th>Maintenance Item</th>
                    <th>March 2015 Maintenance</th>
                    <th>May 2015 Maintenance</th>
                    <th>August 2015 Maintenance</th>
                    <th>October 2015 Maintenance</th>
                    <th>December 2015 Maintenance</th>
                    <th>March 2016 Maintenance</th>
                    <th>May 2016 Maintenance</th>
                    <th>August 2016 Maintenance</th>
                    <th>October 2016 Maintenance</th>
                    <th>December 2016 Maintenance</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Pollen Filter</th>
                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Air Filter</th>
                    <td colspan="5"></td>
                    <td colspan="5"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Brake Flush</th>
                    <td colspan="5"></td>
                    <td colspan="5"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Transmission Flush</th>
                    <td colspan="10"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
     </table>       
</section>
```

CSS

```
table.schedule {
    border: 4px solid rgba(166,206,57,.8);
    border-radius: 6px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

table.schedule thead {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Playball', cursive;
    font-size: 110%;
    border-bottom: 5px solid grey;
}

table.schedule td {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, green, yellow, red);
}

table.schedule tbody th {
font-size: 150%;
padding-bottom: 15px;
padding-top: 15px;
}

table.schedule td {
border: 2px solid rgb(166, 206, 57);
}   

table.schedule th {
    padding: 0px 20px 0px;
}
```

Comment: You can do this with media queries - http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use media queries if your browser supports them. Here is an example where I've used them to alter some of the properties (but not all). Code contains explanatory comments.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* values in here will apply when the browser width is 600px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
    table.schedule tbody th {
        font-size: 80%;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        padding-top: 5px;
    }
}

/* values in here will apply when the browser width is between 601px and 800px inclusive */
@media screen and (min-width:601px) and (max-width: 800px) {
    table.schedule tbody th {
        font-size: 150%;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
}

/* remaining values will apply as normal */
table.schedule {
    border: 4px solid rgba(166,206,57,.8);
    border-radius: 6px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

table.schedule thead {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Playball', cursive;
    font-size: 110%;
    border-bottom: 5px solid grey;
}

table.schedule td {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, green, yellow, red);
}

table.schedule td {
border: 2px solid rgb(166, 206, 57);
}   

table.schedule th {
    padding: 0px 20px 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<section id="scheduleInfo">
<h1 style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><a href="members_home.html" style="text-decoration: none;"><-Back</a></h1>
<h1 style="text-align:center;">Your Personalized Maintenance Schedule</h1>  
<table class="schedule" border="1" summary="scheduleSummary" align="center">
        <caption></caption>
        <colgroup>
            <col class="maintItem" />
            <col class="maint1" />
            <col class="maint2" />
            <col class="maint3" />
            <col class="maint4" />
            <col class="maint5" />
            <col class="maint6" />
            <col class="maint7" />
            <col class="maint8" />
            <col class="maint9" />
            <col class="maint10" />
        </colgroup>
            <thead id="maint">
                <tr>
                    <th>Maintenance Item</th>
                    <th>March 2015 Maintenance</th>
                    <th>May 2015 Maintenance</th>
                    <th>August 2015 Maintenance</th>
                    <th>October 2015 Maintenance</th>
                    <th>December 2015 Maintenance</th>
                    <th>March 2016 Maintenance</th>
                    <th>May 2016 Maintenance</th>
                    <th>August 2016 Maintenance</th>
                    <th>October 2016 Maintenance</th>
                    <th>December 2016 Maintenance</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Pollen Filter</th>
                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Air Filter</th>
                    <td colspan="5"></td>
                    <td colspan="5"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Brake Flush</th>
                    <td colspan="5"></td>
                    <td colspan="5"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Transmission Flush</th>
                    <td colspan="10"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
     </table>       
</section>
</body>
```